Codesys map physical drive to SM_Drive_PosControl
How do I map a physical drive (Servo motor) to SM_Drive_PosControl? Do I need to map all variables individually? Or is there an automatic way to do it?
What I am trying to do is move a physical ethercat servo motor like this:
Power(Axis := SM_Drive_PosControl, Enable := bPowerOn, bRegulatorOn := TRUE, bDriveStart := TRUE);
MoveAbsolute(Axis := SM_Drive_PosControl, Execute := bStart, Position := 200, Velocity := 10, Acceleration := 1000, Deceleration := 1000, Direction := SM3_Basic.MC_DIRECTION.positive);



What does the "Add FB for IO Channel" do? From what it's name is, and the button next to it (go to instance) it should create the function block in your program? Never worked with CodeSys or these drives tho.

I've been wondering about that too.
When i click the button a new window appears, but there's no options, its empty, maybe i have to create it in code first?

Check this link, it should have the information you need. https://content.helpme-codesys.com/en/CODESYS%20Development%20System/_cds_edt_device_io_mapping.html

Have you tried checking the docs for SoftMotion Drives? They even have a demo project.

Just what I needed.

By the way, if you manage to achieve what you wanted, consider submitting your own answer for future visitors
